# How can I add additional syntax highlighting rules in my local vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I installed gvim on both Fedora and Win7. I found that both vim and gvim on Fedora didn't highlight the function name in c code while gvim on win7 did highlight it.

I found that on win7, `vim73/syntax/c.vim` has the additional lines at the end:

```
syn match cFunction "\<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\>[^()]*)("me=e-2 
syn match cFunction "\<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\>\s*("me=e-1 
hi cFunction gui=NONE guifg=#B5A1FF
```

If I add these lines into the `c.vim` on Fedora, gvim can highlight the function name, too.

To maintain the portability, I want to just modify the `.vimrc` to highlight the function name. However after adding these lines into the `.vimrc`, it didn't work.

So, can anyone help me? I did a search and there are many solutions to highlight the function names in vim. But I am just curious about how to make these lines work in `.vimrc`. Thanks very much!

Comment: Try adding it to `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` instead.

Comment: @muru Yes, it works. But how about adding it to `.vimrc`?

Comment: You'd probably have to use something like `autocmd BufEnter *.c hl ...`, but you should keep it in `after/syntax/c.vim`. Any modern version of Vim will understand the `.vim/after/` directory. On Windows, the path would be `vimfiles/after/...`, so portability shouldn't be much of an issue (especially if you use any plugins).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> However after adding these lines into the .vimrc, it didn't work.

The reason for this is that Vim clears existing syntax items when setting the [`'syntax'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27syntax%27) option. This is done because keeping the old syntax items would lead to some strange situations; if you have a buffer which has `syntax=foo` and use `set syntax=bar` then you'll end up with a buffer which has syntax highlighting for *both* `foo` and `bar`.

When Vim starts it loads your `vimrc` once (on startup), but it loads the filetype and syntax files every time the `filetype` or `syntax` options are set, which will reset the values you've set in your vimrc.

Even if it wouldn't reset it, it wouldn't be a good idea to just add it to your vimrc, since it would apply to *all* buffers, and not just buffers with `syntax=c`.

---

The below text assumes Vim on a Unix-y system, but it will work for Neovim and Windows users as well:

- *Neovim* users should replace `~/.vim/` with `~/.config/nvim/`.
- *Windows* users should replace `~/.vim/` with `%USERPROFILE%\vimfiles\`.

### Overriding an entire file

The easiest way to change something is to *just override it*. To do so create a file in `~/.vim/<file>.vim`.

`<file.vim>` is the path relative to `$VIMRUNTIME` (including subdirectories). In your example, it should be `syntax/c.vim`. It will be loaded instead of the file in `$VIMRUNTIME`.

The upshot of this is that it's easier to make changes – amending exiting syntax files can be a bit tricky sometimes. The downside is that you won't get any future updates made to the system-wide file.

I often use this as a *starting point* to experiment with syntax files, and then later extract my local changes to a local addition using one of the methods described below.

### Local additions

There are two ways to add local additions to syntax files, they are functionally identical, and you can use the method you prefer.

#### `Syntax` autocmd

Use the `Syntax` autocmd:

```
augroup ft_c
    autocmd!
    autocmd Syntax c syn match cFunction "\<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\>[^()]*)("me=e-2 
    autocmd Syntax c syn match cFunction "\<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\>\s*("me=e-1 
    autocmd Syntax c hi cFunction gui=NONE guifg=#B5A1FF
augroup end
```

Note that chaining several commands with `|` is problematic here, since they tend to get interpreted as part of the `:syn` command, which is why I've repeated the `autocmd Syntax c` several times. An alternative would be to use a function:

```
fun s:c()
    syn match cFunction "\<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\>[^()]*)("me=e-2 
    syn match cFunction "\<[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\>\s*("me=e-1 
    hi cFunction gui=NONE guifg=#B5A1FF
endfun

augroup ft_c
  autocmd!
  autocmd Syntax c call s:c()
augroup end
```

The advantage is that all changes can be contained to a single file. The disadvantage is that it's a bit ugly, especially if you have a lot of changes.

#### after directory

Use the after-directory: `~/.vim/after/<file>.vim`.

This will be loaded after `<file>.vim` has, where `<file.vim>` is the path relative to `$VIMRUNTIME` (including subdirectories). In your example, it should be `syntax/c.vim`.

Also see [`:help after-directory`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#after%2ddirectory).

The advantage is that it's a bit more readable than the autocmd, especially if you have many changes. The disadvantage is that you'll need to copy over an additional file if you want to mirror your Vim setup to different machines (this is an important reason many people keep their Vim files in a GitHub repo, so it can be easily mirrored across machines).