# How can I highlight WinAPI functions in C++?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, microsoft-windows, filetype-c++, filetype-c

How can I add syntax highlight for `windows.h` C/C++ apis and types?

All I've found is a tiny winapi syntax file [here](https://github.com/fishman/vim_files/blob/master/after/syntax/c/winapi.vim).

Answer (score 3):

You've already found how to highlight these types from the link you've posted in your question; by adding these lines to `after/syntax/c/winapi.vim` (see [How can I add additional syntax highlighting rules in my local vimrc?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10815/51) for more details on that):

```
syn keyword cppWINAPI SetWindowLong
syn keyword cppWINAPIConst WM_CREATE
syn keyword cppWINAPItype HGLOBAL

hi def link cppWINAPI Identifier
hi def link cppWINAPItype Type
hi def link cppWINAPIConst Constant
```

So all we need to do now is to populate this list with additional function, constants, and types.

For example, I found this [Alphabetical list of Win32 and COM API in Windows 8.x apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn424765.aspx). With some JS-fu in my console I got a space-separated list of all the functions:

```
$('#mainSection li a strong')
    .map(function() { return $(this).html() })
    .toArray()
    .join(' ')
```

Which I then copied & pasted in the `after/syntax/c/winapi.vim` file:

```
syn keyword cppWINAPI _IRDPSessionEvents AcquireSRWLockExclusive [..etc..]
```

This doesn't separate out functions, constants, and types though; and I have no idea how complete it is. But this is the basic procedure to make such a file.

---

If you want a more complete list then you can perhaps try using one of the answers in [Win32 API to enumerate dll export functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1128150/660921) to export the information from the WinAPI libraries.

There is also the [Windows API Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx). It's split over a whole bunch of pages, but the layout seems fairly consistent. Extracting that would require a script and some work, but is probably doable.