# Vim highlights valid shell parameter expansion syntax as an error

Tags: syntax-highlighting, neovim, filetype-sh

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${2:-"-l -p"}
```

Having some bash parameter-substitution fun and (Neo) Vim complains about it, while the code is perfectly fine.

I know I can suppress errors totally by doing sort of like `hi Error ctermbg=None`, but that's quick and dirty. (I can live with the red background, but it's ugly).

I did `:h error` [[ press Tab 20 times ]], but didn't find anything interesting about the topic.

Can I fix (or should I report) such misbehaviour?

Pure Vim highlights the same way, running:

```
vim -u NONE -c "set nocp | set filetype=sh | syn on"
```

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 15 2016 18:06:04)
Included patches: 1-86
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version without GUI.
```

**Update**

Doesn't work in urxvt. Neither in neo nor pure Vim.
Doesn't work in NeoVim. Neither in urxvt nor xterm.
Works only in xterm, pure Vim.

works == no red background, I mean
All of the above happens with `-u NONE`.

Comment: Can't reproduce here, even with the "pure vim" configuration (OS X, MacVim 8). Could it be something related to your terminal?

Comment: It's strange that this would work correctly in xterm/Vim, but doesn't in urxvt/Vim. Are you sure you're using the same Vim version in both tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim also *used* to display this as an error, but the latest version no longer does. It looks like the syntax file for Vim has been updated in a fairly recent version Vim, which isn't in Neovim yet.

I downloaded the Vim source and did:

```
git checkout v7.4.1900
```

To get an older Vim version. We're only interested in the syntax file (`runtime/syntax/sh.vim`) so we don't need to re-compile Vim.

After opening a simple `a.sh` file which contains `echo ${2:-"-l -p"}` I did:

```
:unlet b:current_syntax
:source /home/martin/src/vim/runtime/syntax/sh.vim
```

to load the Vim 7.4.1900 syntax file from the source tree, and now I have the same red text as you do.

So now we need to isolate the patch that fixes this. Unfortunately the git commits for runtime directories don't contain a helpful description (just "update runtime directory") but we know that:

- v8.0.0142 does *not* have this problem;
- v7.4.1900 *does* have this problem;
- that the fix is in `runtime/syntax/sh.vim`

Checking the [history for that file](https://github.com/vim/vim/commits/master/runtime/syntax/sh.vim) we see there aren't that many recent changes, so I simply did `git checkout <commit-id>` until I managed to reproduce the problem. The commit after that one will have fixed the problem, which is [`e4a3bcf`](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/e4a3bcf28d92d0bde9ca227ccb40d401038185e5#diff-3684eb3d10603a1e201bf60108720b02).

if you look at the diff, we see a number of changes to the `shDeref*` syntax groups, which seem fix the error.

There are two things you can do:

- Copy the latest `syntax/sh.vim` from the Vim source to to `~/.config/nvim/syntax/sh.vim` (Neovim) or `~/.vim/syntax/sh.vim` (Vim) so it will override the default. Neovim doesn't seem to have [made any changes to this file](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commits/master/runtime/syntax/sh.vim), so you won't lose anything.

  The downside of this is that you won't get any future updates made to the system-wide `syntax/sh.vim`.
- You can also try to locally amend the `syntax/sh.vim` file with just the fixes [using the after directory](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4975/51). This will take more time, but you will get future updates made to the system-wide `syntax/sh.vim`.

Comment: Whooa you *did* investigate this :) Thank you very much, I'll try your suggestion now. I think I had some problem with xbindkeys (which I use to start `urxvt`). I ran `urxvt` manually and then the pure vim colors were ok. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the urxvt/pure vim misbehaviour any more. I have not updated any of them since, so that's really weird.

Comment: OK, swapping the default `sh.vim` in neovim with the latest one from vim works. But I don't think it's worth the effort just for some dummy red background on line 53 in /home/user/path/to/file.... :) It was interesting solution anyway, so thanks again +1.5 :). I think, though, I should reconsider using neovim vs pure vim.

Comment: Carpetsmoker, this would have been an excellent time to use `git bisect`.