# How can I remove a syntax keyword?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-python

In Python3, `file` is no longer a builtin. It's just a plain ol' name that isn't even associated with anything until you do. But all the syntax files that I've used have it as a builtin.

Is there a simple way (I checked `:help syn` to look for an antonym, but nothing jumped out at me) to remove `file` from the syntax category, or do I pretty much just have to define my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Note: the Python 2 keywords were removed in February 2021 with Vim [8.2.2554](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/9faec4e3d#diff-70532bfa8e84bebf0348b1ca9c76559c4c5997dc1853cf3dbdb0944ac315adc5L212)*).

---

You'll have to look at the syntax file and undo what it's doing. You can find the syntax file with `:e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/python.vim`, and with `/file` I found:

```
" Python 2 only
syn keyword pythonBuiltin     basestring cmp execfile file
syn keyword pythonBuiltin     long raw_input reduce reload unichr
syn keyword pythonBuiltin     unicode xrange

[..]

" non-essential built-in functions; Python 2 only
syn keyword pythonBuiltin     apply buffer coerce intern
```

As far as I know there is no way to remove keywords from the `syn keyword` declaration, so you'll have to either:

1. Clear the `pythonBuiltin` declarations with `:syn clear pythonBuiltin` and define your own with just the Python 3 ones: `syn keyword pythonBuiltin abs all any [...]`
2. Override the Python 3 ones; e.g. `:syn keyword pythonTwoBuiltin file`.

The first method is arguably a bit "cleaner", but with the second method you will retain future additions to `pythonBuiltin` from the system's file. It will also allow you to do something like `:hi link pythonTwoBuiltin pythonBuiltin` to highlight the Python 2 builtins in case you find yourself editing Python 2 code.

I would personally opt for the second method, and added this to my vimrc:

```
" Remove Python 2 keywords.
augroup angering_zed_shaw
    autocmd!
    autocmd Syntax python
        \ syn keyword pythonTwoBuiltin basestring cmp execfile file long
        \                              raw_input reduce reload unichr unicode
        \                              xrange apply buffer coerce intern
augroup end
```

Note you can't just add this to your vimrc file; you'll have to use an autocmd or the `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim` file. See [How can I add additional syntax highlighting rules in my local vimrc?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4975/51) for details on that.

Comment: I wish I could +2 for `angering_zed_shaw` :D