# manually set syntax highlighting works from command-line mode but not from .vimrc/init.vim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, syntax-highlighting, filetype-c++, filetype-c

The gruvbox colorscheme and syntax highlighting for C++ doesn't highlight some elements such as:

- `string`
- `vector`

I have this:

[image]

So I decided to change the colors manually using in `init.vim`

```
syn keyword Type string
syn keyword Type vector
```

This method didn't work.

When I run these commands myself while editing a file, I get the following change:

[image]

[image]

It works like a charm:

[image]

My goal is to automatically change colors for `string`, `vector`, `cout` and many more keywords from `init.vim`, because by default they are not highlighted by gruvbox.

- neovim version (nightly-nvim from AUR):

```
NVIM v0.5.0-dev+1391-g1df8a34a7
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
```

- neofetch:

[image]

In `init.vim` I have:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

---

I have also tried the after-directory option. I placed a new file called  `after_init.vim` in these directories:

- `~/.config/nvim/after/after_init.vim`
- `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/after_init.vim`
- `~/.vim/after/after_init.vim`
- `~/.vim/after/syntax/after_init.vim`

with:

```
syn keyword Type string
syn keyword Type vector
echon "im loaded after init.vim"
```

This also did not work.

I then also tried the autocommand option in `init.vim`:

```
augroup ft_c
    autocmd!
    autocmd Syntax c syn keyword Type string
    autocmd Syntax c syn keyword Type vector
augroup end
```

This didn't work.

Comment: Syntax highlighting depends on the contents of the buffer being parsed according to its file type. This doesn't happen until after your vimrc has been processed. There are a lot of posts here addressing this. I'll see if I can find a good one.  .... Found one linked right there in the right margin: [How can I add additional syntax highlighting rules in my local vimrc?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4975)

Comment: okey, `syn` doesnt work in `init.vim`. i saw the option with `after directory` (check updated answer)

Comment: clearly im missing something... or i dont know or understand enough nvim?

Comment: Where did you get "after_init.vim"? There's no mention of a file like that in the linked answer or in the help section you cited.

Comment: I've made some [edit]s to clean up the post. [Please don't post images of text, unless you're demonstrating something graphical](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/); I've changed one image to text myself, since it only contained version information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files in the `syntax` directory should be named after the filetype detected by Vim. In the case of your C++ code, I'd expect it would detect it as `cpp`. You can check that with the following command:

```
:set filetype?
cpp
```

Or you can use `:set ft?` for short.

Once you confirm that the filetype is indeed `cpp`, you can create file `~/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim` (for Vim) or `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/cpp.vim` (for NeoVim) with the `syn` commands you want to load after the built-in rules are loaded:

```
syn keyword Type string
syn keyword Type vector
```

Comment: solved the problem. thank you so much. if i want for python i have to set `python.vim`, correct?

Comment: Yes! `python` is the correct filetype for Python.

Comment: okey. thanks man, very much appreciate.