# When editing vim script files (*.vim), line continuations are not highlighted properly

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

When I edit VIM syntax highlighting definitions or any other VIM script file (*.vim), I lose syntax highlighting on lines that are continued from the previous one. For example,

```
syntax region LongRegionNameToTakeUpSpaceOnThisLine matchgroup=String
\   oneline contained start=+"+ end=+"+ skip=+\\"+
\   contains=Foo,Bar containedin=AnotherRegion
```

should have full syntax highlighting for all three lines (i.e., "contains," "containedin," "skip," "start," "end," "oneline," and "contained" should all be highlighted as key words, just like "matchgroup" is). Instead, I only get highlighting on the first line.

Does this happen for other users, too, or is it specific to my installation or something in my settings? I can confirm that it is still not working if I don't source my vimrc (e.g., "vim -u NONE test.vim").

This used to work in VIM 7.3 (on Fedora), but VIM 7.4 (Ubuntu 16.04.6), VIM 8.2 (Fedora 34), and VIM 9.0 (Fedora 35) don't work correctly for me unless I fall back to an old syntax definition file (vim.vim). I can't find anything really obvious in the syntax definition files that changed for the linecont code.

Comment: It seems to work for me in Vim 9.0.35 if I put just that snippet in a new file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qhji.png – it could be there's something else in the file that confuses things; does it work if you have a file with *only* that snippet? Also, which patch version are you using (the second line of output in `:version`).

Comment: You can also try using the command at the top of [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37946/51) to see if anything matches.

Comment: @MartinTournoij 9.0.57 and `vim -u DEFAULTS -U NONE`, paste, `:setf vim` and the highlight is wrong until I join the continued lines. OTOH, a random script in my dotfiles with line continuations works fine.

Comment: Interesting; I installed 9.0.57 and did exactly the same as your instructions @D.BenKnoble, and it still works for me.

Comment: I can reproduce this. Inspecting the region, it seems most of it is matching the `vimIsCommand` syntax group.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Looking at your PNG, it seems to me that it's *not* working, since I'd expect the "oneline", "contained", "start", "end", "skips", "contains" and "containedin" all to highlight the same as "matchgroup", but you can clearly see they're different. If you join the three lines, you'll see it will update the highlighting of those keywords.

Comment: @MartinTournoij if it was working, "start" and "end" would be green in your example (as would "skip" and the words "contained," "oneline," "contained," and "containedin" would be magenta (like "matchgroup"). I'm not able to attach images, but I did get this to work with an old (VIM 7.3-based) file, but only if I put the backslash at the beginning of the line, cut the first line, pasted it back in, then pressed "tab" to indent the backslash. So perhaps it has never worked "well" even in old versions.

Comment: I managed to fix this (sort of) using the following line in ~/.vim/after/syntax/vim.vim:
syn region vimSynRegion contained keepend matchgroup=vimGroupName start="\h\w*" skip="\n\s*\\" end="|\|$" contains=@vimSynRegGroup

This basically replaces skip="\\\\\|\\|" with skip="\n\s*\\"

Comment: Ahhh, do'h; you are right @filbranden; I was just looking at the `\\` character at the start of the line as I thought that's what the question was about, and not the rest 

Comment: happens in neovim v8.0, too. syntax done with regex is bound to have edge cases like this. sadly.